# In Amplitude Modulation transmission, why do we need to mix (multiply) rather than just add the carrier and base-band?

Tags: rf, radio, transmitter, mixer, amplitude-modulation

Why is it necessary to mix the carrier with the message signal to create the sum and difference of the frequencies when you can just add both signal?
Not only is it much easier to achieve but it would also just contain only the carrier and message frequency harmonics.

I think the reason is because only the high frequency harmonic would be able to get transmitted am I correct?

Comment: Your goal is to add frequency, so you have to multiply amplitude. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModulationTheorem.html if you add amplitude the frequency is unchanged.

Comment: If all you did was add, then only the carrier would make it through all the RF tuned circuits between that stage and the receiver output.

Answer (score 1):

If you just added, then all the baseband energy would still be in the baseband. 0 - 5 kHz or so, assuming we're talking about analog. So it wouldn't be transmitted by an antenna that works at 531 - 1602 kHz.

It also wouldn't be separated from the signal of any other channel operating on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want baseband + carrier.

you do want carrier plus two sidebands of equal power that have phases rotating in opposite directions, so all phase variation cancels out, leaving only amplitude information.